# Borrar datos anteriores en java

Tags: java, lista, nodos

Tengo un problema con un código, trata de eliminar de una lista los números menores a una clave introducida por el usuario, el problema llega cuando la lista se queda vacía, en este caso me salta: *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException*

En cambio si todavía quedan números en la lista no da error.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
public void eliminar(int numero) {
        Nodo now = start;
        Nodo before = null;
        while((now!=null)&&(now.getNumero()<numero)){
            before = now;
            now = now.getNext();
        }
        if(now==null) {
            start = now.getNext();
        }
        else before.setNext(actual.getNext());
    }
```

El nodo está definido así:

```
public class Nodo {
    private Numero dato;
    private Nodo next;
```

Y el código está dentro de :

```
public class Lista {
    public Nodo start;
    private int cantidad;
```

Como os habréis dado cuenta no disminuyo la cantidad de nodos cada vez que elimino un numero pero es que lo ponga donde lo ponga nunca disminuye bien.

Siguiendo el código de Glenn Sandoval :

```
public void eliminar(int numero) {
    Nodo now = start;
    Nodo before = null;
    while((now!=null)&&(now.getNumero()<numero)){
        before = now;
        now = now.getNext();
    }

    if(now == null) { // No encontró la clave porque todos fueron menores que 'numero'
        start = null; // Lista vacía
        return;
    }

    if(before != null)
        before.setNext(now.getNext());
    else
        start = now.getNext();
}
```

El error salta en la linea `before.setNext(now.getNext());`

Gracias por llegar hasta aquí y si tenéis alguna sugerencia os la agradezco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás cometiendo un error en el `if(now == null) start = now.getNext();` naturalmente al llamar a `getNext()` desde un objeto en `null` te va a lanzar un `NullPointerException`.

No estoy seguro de que el siguiente código funcione porque no lo puedo probar pero reemplaza la función `eliminar` y modifica lo necesario:

```
public void eliminar(int numero) {
    Nodo now = start;
    Nodo before = null;
    while((now!=null)&&(now.getNumero()<numero)){
        before = now;
        now = now.getNext();
    }

    if(now == null) { // No encontró la clave porque todos fueron menores que 'numero'
        start = null; // Lista vacía
        return;
    }

    if(before != null)
        before.setNext(now.getNext());
    else
        start = now.getNext();
}
```

Comment: Gracias aunque me sigue saliendo el mismo el error :(

Comment: @Pau Revisa bien la línea en la que te da error y edita la pregunta indicando el punto exacto donde se cae el programa, hay un dato en `null` en ese punto.

Comment: El error viene de : ```before.setNext(now.getNext());```

Answer (score 3):

Todo el problema radica aquí:

```java
if(now==null) {
   start = now.getNext();
}
```

Cuando la referencia `now` apunte a `null`, ocurrirá la excepción `NullPointerException` en esta línea:

```java
------------
           |
start = now.getNext();
```

> > Tengo un problema con un código, trata de eliminar de una lista los números menores a una clave introducida por el usuario

Tu código no hace eso, debido a que, en ningún momento se  actualiza la referencia `start` cuando el primer nodo tiene un número que sea menor a la clave.

La solución (en algoritmo) sería así:

**1.-** La referencia `now` apuntará a lo mismo que `start` la primera vez y `before` a `null`.

**2.-** Se comprueba si la referencia `now` apunta a `null`, esta sería la condición de salida del bucle `while`.

**3.-** Se verifica si el nodo al que apunte `now` tiene un número menor a la clave.

Si la condición se cumple, verificamos si el contenido de la referencia `now` coincide con `start`, con esto se comprueba que el número a "eliminar" está en el primer nodo, por lo tanto, debemos **actualizar** la referencia `start` para que apunte al siguiente nodo, ya que ese **nodo** sería el primero.

Si esta condición no se llegara a cumplir, esto quiere decir, que el número a "eliminar" está en un nodo intermedio (es decir, que no está en el inicio), por ende, debemos actualizar el campo siguiente del nodo al que apunte `before`, ya que apuntará al nodo que apunte el campo siguiente del nodo al que apunte `now`.

**4.-** Si la condición **principal** del paso `3` no se llegara a cumplir, le asignamos el contenido de `now` a `before`.

**5.-** Por último actualizamos la referencia `now`.

En código Java quedaría así:

```java
public void eliminar(int numero)
{
    Nodo now = start;
    Node before = null;
    while(now != null)
    {
        if(now.getNumero() < numero)
        {
            //Si es el primer nodo...
            if(now == start)
                start = now.getNext();
            else //Si es un nodo intermedio...
                before.setNext(now.getNext());
        }
        else
            before = now;
        now = now.getNext();
    }
}
```

Hagamos la prueba si realmente este algoritmo funcionará.

Imaginemos que tenemos esta lista de números y nuestra clave es el `2`:

```java
Lista enlazada simple:
before = null
start 
 |
[1        -     0      -        2       -   0]
 |
now
```

La referencia `now` apunta al nodo `1` y tiene un número menor a `2`, por lo tanto, la condición `start == now` se cumple y actualizamos la referencia `start`, así que ahora apunta al segundo nodo. Pero ten en cuenta que la referencia `before` seguirá apuntando a `null`, porque estamos asumiendo que antes del primer nodo no hay ningún otro nodo, por lo tanto, solo actualizamos `now`:

```java
Lista enlazada simple:
before = null
start
  |
[ 0      -        2       -   0]
  |
  now
```

Como el nodo al que apunte `now` otra vez tiene un número menor a la clave, se aplica el mismo procedimiento anterior, quedando así la lista:

```java
Lista enlazada simple:
before = null
start
  |
[ 2       -   0]
  |
  now
```

Aquí la cosa cambia, la referencia `now` ahora apunta a un nodo en la cual tiene un número que no es mayor ni menor a la clave, sino, igual. Así que la condición no se cumple y ahora si debemos tener una referencia que apunte al nodo anterior y a su vez, se actualiza `now`, quedando así la lista:

```java
Lista enlazada simple:
start
  |
[ 2       -   0]
  |           |
 before      now
```

El último nodo si tiene un número que es menor a la clave, por lo tanto, se actualizará a `null` el campo siguiente del primer nodo. Y al final, `now` valdrá `null`, quedando la lista de esta manera:

```java
Lista enlazada simple:
start
[2]
```

Y básicamente así es como funciona el algoritmo.

> > Borrar datos anteriores en java

Los datos nunca se borrarán (permanecen en memoria), ni siquiera puedes liberar la memoria (porque en Java no se puede gestionar la memoria manualmente), básicamente el recolector de basura de Java se encargará de hacerlo por ti.